# MySQL cluster Slave is having missing records

Tags: mysql, database-connection, database-administration, database-replication

I have a mysql cluster with a master(m1) and a slave(s1) nodes. I have setup asynchronous replication.
I am inserting data into a table in m1 using 10 threads of a data ingestion python script.

Case I: I inserted 1.07M records into a table (t1) in m1. All 1.07M records replicated to slave(s1).

Case II: Master node crashed, so I switched over existing slave to new master (s1->m2). Then restored a new mysql instance. The new mysql instance has 1.07M records which were applied as part of restore logic. The new mysql instance is added as new slave (s2) to new master(m2). Now MySQL cluster has Master (m2) and slave (s2). Asynchronous replication.

Case III: I inserted 1M records into same table (t1) in m2. Now master has 2.07M records for table (t1) whereas I see the slave have 2.05M records. So .02 records are missing in the slave.

I observed this issue regularly. Is this issue a know one?

Comment: How are you measuring the number of rows in the tables? `SHOW TABLE STATUS`? Are you aware that the row counts reported by that statement are only estimates?

Comment: I am querying using count(*) `select count(*) from db.table; `. Yes sir, I am aware of it. :)

Comment: Okay, I had to ask, because many software developers are not aware of that.

Comment: There are several ways that records could fail to be applied on the replica. I'd make sure to use ROW based replication and binlog checksums. I also recommend using [pt-table-sync](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-table-sync.html) to get the replica back in sync.

Comment: Yes ROW binlog formart. Checksums for data validation only. Doesn't fix the pbm. No tools please. Please let me know if anything else available out of the box.

Comment: Out of the box? Destroy the slave, and take a new snapshot from the master to create a new slave.